# git clone exclude lfs file

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-lfs

I'm struggling with git (2.24.0), git-lfs (not installed) and a continuous integration pipeline (until now I've tried with circleci and github actions).

Given that in CI machine there is no git-lfs installed, I expect that after executing git clone, only regular files will appear, but I see an lfs file created (almost empty, 138 bytes).

I've stressed the continuous integration thing because on my computer git clone behaves differently, i.e. not creating the lfs file at all.

How to exclude those placeholder lfs files to be created?

Comment: Something is wrong about what you're saying you see.  In the absence of LSF, git does not know the difference between an LFS pointer file and any other file. In any case I'm not sure how you would prevent a checkout from creating *something* at the path where the pointer file is found. (With LFS installed, a filter replaces the pointer with the real content; you could use a different filter to just empty the file, but (1) the file would still be there, and (2) it would likely cause problems if you restaged the file.)  So I suspect some sort of observation error here ...

Comment: ... But in any case, the behavior you describe on the CI system is correct.  If LFS is not present, then the pointer file "looks like" a normal file to git, and it just gets copied into the working tree like anything else.  I suppose you could script something using path-specific checkouts to first read the gitattributes files, and then read any file not matched by an LFS filter attribute; but that would not be easy (nor likely worth it).  There might be an alternative that would make sense, if we knew what you were really trying to accomplish